# Protractor with Firefox : Failed: Error while running testForAngular: Document was unloaded

Tags: protractor

In chrome tests runs fine, but I get this error every time I run my test in Firefox browser:

`Failed: Error while running testForAngular: Document was unloaded [stack]
Error: Error while running testForAngular: Document was unloaded at executeAsyncScript_.then (C:\jenkins\workspace\QA-E2E-Firefox-Win10\automation\TestAutomation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:727:23)`

Comment: What are the Protractor and Firefox versions you are using?

Comment: Firefox : 57.0.2, Protractor : 5.2.2

Comment: Does it happen at the end of the tests or after the Firefox has started? Do you see the browser opened? Do you see your application loaded there?

Comment: Are you working with non-angular app? I mean it may be due to waitforangular calls. try to run test cases in firefox with   browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

Comment: browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; did not help, its an Angular App, in chrome my test runs fine but on Firefox most of the test fails with same error : `Failed: Error while running testForAngular: Document was unloaded`

Comment: @alecxe it happens for most of the test I can see browser is opening and my application is loaded few test case will be run and pass but after sometime all the test will fail saying `Failed: Error while running testForAngular: Document was unloaded` screenshot does not show anything its just a blank screen.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. I suggest you divide and conquer. Try executing your tests one by one and see if they pass separately. Then, try to execute more and more tests sequentially and notice when the problem starts to happen..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by using the selenium server to interact with the browser driver instead of protractor directly interacting with the browser driver, following changes has been made to my conf.js file.

directConnect: false,
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'