# JavaScriptError: Document was unloaded error when trying to take screenshots

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, jasmine, protractor

For my e2e tests in protractor I want to take screenshots for various routes on my angular project. So I wrote the following code which takes a url from an array of url's and feeds it into the following function. I ran this code for chrome and it works fine all the screenshots are taken and saved on desired place, but when I run it for Firefox it throws error for about 4-5 urls from the array of 39 urls and these 4-5 urls may change it may or may not occur for the same url on the second run.

```
    async function WantToTakeGoldenScreenshots(urlForWhichScreenshot,rank){
    console.log("1")
    await browser.get(urlForWhichScreenshot)
    console.log("2")

    const png = await browser.takeScreenshot()
    var ImagePath =  path + RouteName 
    var stream =  createWriteStream( ImagePath+'.png'); 
    stream.write(Buffer.from(png, 'base64'));
    stream.end; 
    console.log("3")

}


    describe('Function to take golden screenshot of all url in list',  () => { 

        var urlListlength = urlList.length
          for (let i = 0; i < urlListlength; i++) {
             it('screenshot taken', async() => {
              console.log("0")    
             await WantToTakeGoldenScreenshots(  urlList[i],i)  
              console.log("test end")
             // Goto Function(2a)      
             });
          // }
        }
    });
```

The error thrown is:

```
0
1
    ✗ screenshot taken
      - Failed: Error while running testForAngular: JavaScriptError: Document was unloaded

NOTE: In console 2 and 3 are not printed but in cases that passes all are shown in a sequence
```

I am not able to solve this issue I was not using async await previously so thought this might be the problem so I added that, now also it is not working. What should I do ?

Comment: @yevhen Do you have any thoughs on this ?

Comment: `.then() ;{` and `stream.end;` seem really wrong.

Comment: @Bergi So what should I do ?

Comment: Well, what did you want these to do? Have a look at their documentation on how they are properly used. (Or in the case of `.then()`, take your other usage as an example)

Comment: Should I add my config file also ?

Comment: Are you sure your js is not navigating or unloading page?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102519/protractor-with-firefox-failed-error-while-running-testforangular-document-w?rq=1)

Comment: @Stefdelec In config files--> onPrepare method I have code that navigates to the login page of my website

Comment: @DublinDev that did not help

Comment: @johnsmith I'm seeing a [few threads](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1283) stating that the issue typically resolves if a wait is introduced however I agree that it is better to actually understand the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using async / await so that must mean you are using `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in your Protractor config. This is great that you are using async / await since the control flow has been deprecated for a while.

I am not sure what is in your URL list but the `testForAngular` issue is around navigating to a page and checking if Angular is stable. Basically when Angular is running a zone and does change detection, events, etc. After Angular returns from a zone, it tells Protractor that the page must be stable. For a page that is not Angular, this would throw an error because Protractor is waiting for a "stable" page.

### How to prevent `testForAngular` from being called

There are two options to prevent this error from happening. The first option is to use `browser.ignoreSynchronization` and the other is to use the async method `browser.waitForAngularEnabled`. Remember if you decide to go to a page that is not Angular, you will have to come up with your own checks for synchronization. An example of this might be to simply check to see if a web element is visible (try to avoid just blindly setting sleeps).

#### Option 1: `browser.ignoreSynchronization` (will be deprecated)

So how can you stop checking `testForAngular`? You could set the browser property `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` (this has been noted as deprecated in the comments as of Protractor v5 and eventually will be removed). Doing this will prevent Protractor from running `testForAngular`. You could add `browser.ignoreSynchronization` to your `onPrepare` plugin or `beforeAll` / `beforeEach` block.

#### Option 2: `browser.waitForAngularEnabled`

The next option is to use the async method: `browser.waitForAngularEnabled`. This is an async getter and setter. So you could check the value of it with `await browser.waitForAngularEnabled()` or you could set the value `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`. Basically you want to set it to the opposite of the `ignoreSynchronization` value (in this case, if you were thinking about setting the ignoreSynchronization value to true, then you want to set this value of false).

Comment: Of course this is just a guess at the `Failed: Error while running testForAngular: JavaScriptError: Document was unloaded` error message. It might help to add your configuration file

Comment: Thanks now its working fine for firefox.  urlList contains routes in the website for eg. `urlList = ["/tutorial/toh-pt1"]` and `baseurl: "https://angular.io/"`. But the issue is my page gets loaded every time I do `browser.get(urlList[1])` I thought it would only navigate to a route without reloading the webpage like in an angular app

Comment: what do you think about the problem mentioned in comment above

Comment: When you navigate with browser.get the entire page is loaded. I believe what you want is to not refresh, so this would require you to start at the angular.io page and click on buttons till you find the /tutorial/toh-pt1 path

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the configuration and the page load speed there can be more than one reason for `Document was unloaded` error.

Few pointers that can help in finding the root cause (or fixing) it:

1. Make sure `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER` is set to `false` given you are taking the responsibility to `await`/`async` yourself
2. If the above is already in place, then remove all async and awaits and let Protractor handle that for you. Do not forget to remove the flag set in above step.
3. If that doesn't fix the issue then, give browser a little bit of time **BEFORE** `browser.get` is called. Its not a fix per se, but to see if the page load time and/or screenshot API is causing the issue in Firefox.

Hope that helps.

Comment: We had 2. in place did not work I thought I should add async/await so tried 1. still did not work and we had 3 in place for both the cases. Thanks for your input

Comment: The future is async / await. You should set the SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER to false.